# Yii2 showScriptName gives me 404s

Tags: routes, yii2

Setting showScriptName gives me a 404 error. I've got a SiteController which goes like this:

```
class SiteController extends Controller
{
        public function actionIndex() {
            return $this->render('index');
        }

        public function actionJoin() {
            return $this->render('join');
        }

        public function actionLogin() {
            return $this->render('login');
        }
}
```

Corresponding files are in:

```
λ ls -lah views\site\
total 3,0K
drwxr-xr-x 1 user 197121  0 дек 28 15:43 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 user 197121  0 дек 27 10:40 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 user 197121 16 дек 27 10:42 index.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 user 197121 16 дек 28 15:43 join.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 user 197121 15 дек 28 15:44 login.php
```

My navbar widget is:

```
$menu = [
    ['label' => 'Join', 'url' => ['/site/join']],
    ['label' => 'Log in', 'url' => ['/site/login']]
];
echo Nav::widget([
    'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav navbar-right'],
    'items' => $menu
]);
```

Works like a charm giving me urls like:

```
myapp.test/index.php/site/login
```

But if set showScriptName to true in config\web.php, it starts giving me 404s. How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Basically found on SO after just a little bit of the searching, so all credits goes to skyc:

SOLUTION: Missing /backend/web/.htaccess file

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . index.php

Comment: you should close the question as duplicate rather than adding an answer here so that others who land on this page should be redirected to the correct answer.